# Jmeter Groovy replacing JSON file

Tags: groovy, jmeter

In Jmeter JSR223Preprocessor with Groovy I load a generic JSON file xyz looking like this:

```
    {
  "name": "dummy",
  "block1": {
    "var1": 1,
    "var2": {
"value": 1,
  "unit": "Miles",
 },  
    "var3": {
"value": 3,
  "unit": "Seconds",
 },  
  "myList": [{"Id": 0}]
}
```

I like to come up with an elegant way to replace the var2  "Value" with a configurable value sayconfVal.  This works:

```
String path = vars.get("basePath")+"xyz.json" ;
xyz = new File(path).getText("UTF-8");
xyz = xyz.replaceAll ('"value": 1', '"value": ${confVal}');
```

However I am not comfortable with this because it is vulnerable with spaces, and moreover I have another Value on var3 and someone could accidentally change 1 to 3. So I like to index to that child var2.Value then get Value.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request which body you need to amend
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def xyz = new File(vars.get("basePath")+"xyz.json")
   def request = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(xyz)
   request.block1.var2.value=vars.get('confVal') as int
   xyz.newWriter().withWriter { writer ->
       writer << new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(request).toPrettyString()
   }
   ```
3. That's it, the value in the file should be replaced with what you have in the `${confVal}` variable in the runtime.

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)